# Download binary data into file using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I want to upload and download the files using javascript.

**Step 1:** I converted the uploaded files to binary code and successfully able to send the binary code to server through web api.

```
       var SA_Supp_Evidence_Object_File = null;
        var Evidence_file_name = null;

        if (document.getElementById("file").files.length != 0) {
            SA_Supp_Evidence_Object_File = document.getElementById('file').files[0];

            var fr = new FileReader;
            fr.onloadend = function () {
                alert(fr.result);
            };
            fr.readAsBinaryString(SA_Supp_Evidence_Object_File);

            Evidence_file_name = SA_Supp_Evidence_Object_File.name;
        };
```

**Step 2:** Now i want to retrieve the same data from database and able to download by clicking the link

```
<td><a href="_self">Download</a></td>
```

Can any one help me to solve this problem

I tried like this

```
var data = 'data:text/plain;base64,'+L_EncodedData;
document.location = data;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the `href` attribute of the `<a>` to contain the data you want the user to download. You don't want to do a redirect via `document.location`, instead the anchor itself should contain the data.

e.g.:

```
var a = document.body.appendChild(
    document.createElement("a")
);
a.download = "filename.dat";
a.href = "data:text/plain;base64," + L_EncodedData;
a.innerHTML = "download";
```

Comment: <a href="data:image/jpeg;base64,skjdfbsdhfbsmhdfbsmdhfvbsdvfnsdvfnsdfvsndvfnsdvfnsdvbfbnsdvbfnsd
sdmfsdvbnbfbvsdnbfvsndbfvnsdbvfnsdvfnsdbfnsdbvfsndbvfnsdbvfsnd
smdmfvsmndbvfnsbdvfsdnbfvsndbfvsdbnfvsbdfvsdb" download="filename.png">sdfsdfsdfs</a>
Not working in IE

Comment: IE doesn't fully support inline data yet. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme